# Pagination within Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble including pagination within the bootstrap tabs which are inside a modal.

The following is the code:-

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body" >
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" >
        <li  class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" id="button1" >Basics</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" id="button2" >Concern</a></li>
      </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" >


      <ul class="pager" id="myTab" >
        <li class="next"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" >Next &rarr;</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" >
      <ul class="pager" id="myTab" >
        <li class="previous"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">&larr; Previous</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

  </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The next and previous buttons work, but when I try a next-previous-next combo the tab is still in the first tab but the color of the second tab changes. What could be the error?

Comment: Do you use a pagination plugin? If yes which one? If not post your code.

Comment: It is made using Jquery and it is taken from Bootstrap. I read somewhere that pagination with tabs is not supported but I can't figure out what the error is.

Comment: In most cases pagination plugins are bound to the page and not to some div. So they see the whole page as something that has to be included in pagination. Since your tabs are all in one html page they are included by the pagination plugin and mess the whole thing up.

Comment: So any alternatives to this issue?

Comment: I don't know any already made solutions to this. You might have to build something yourself. But I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it! Keeping just the link for the Previous and Next buttons and removing the pagination classes and ids seemed to solve it. If you could write this as the answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: No it's ok. You should write it and accept it. You found a solution on your own. I merely provided some tips. Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. Removing the list classes and keeping the link for the next and previous button seems to fix it.